# Hang during databinding of large amount of data to WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, binding

Im using WPFToolkit datagrid control and do the binding in such way:

```
<WpfToolkit:DataGrid x:Name="dgGeneral" SelectionMode="Single"
                              SelectionUnit="FullRow"
                              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                              CanUserAddRows="False"
                              CanUserDeleteRows="False" 
                              Grid.Row="1"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Conversations}" >
```

```
public List<CONVERSATION> Conversations
        {
            get { return conversations; }
            set
            {
                if (conversations != value)
                {
                    conversations = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("Conversations");
                }
            }
        }  

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged; 

public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

public void GenerateData()
         {
            BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();

            bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            List<CONVERSATION> list = new List<CONVERSATION>();

            bw.DoWork += delegate { list = RefreshGeneralData(); };

            bw.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate
                                         {
                                             try
                                             {
                                                 Conversations = list;
                                             }
                                             catch (Exception ex)
                                             {
                                                 CustomException.ExceptionLogCustomMessage(ex);
                                             }

                                         };

            bw.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
```

And than in the main window i call GenerateData() after setting DataCotext of the window to instance of the class, containing GenerateData().

RefreshGeneralData() returns some list of data i want and it returns it fast. 

Overall there are near 2000 records and 6 columns(im not posting the code i used during grid's initialization, because i dont think it can be the reason) and the grid hangs for almost 10 secs! 

---
**PS** i found the project, that is written in similar way, but even binding of 50000 records is done without UI hang there! What am i doing wrong?
**UPDATE** i think that's because of ScrollViewer, which contains the whole grid in it. But why?

Comment: the question is: how can i speed up the binding?

Comment: or may be you can just give me the direction..About how to bind data to datagrid properly. Im new to WPF and didn't expected such kind of problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you explicitely disable it, the items in the DataGrid are virtualized, i.e. only the items currently shown are rendered. You might be having a problem due to UI Automation (this was fixed in .NET 4). See http://wpf.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=41964

This can happen if you have a Wacom tablet or a screen reader installed.

Comment: No..I use .NET4 Client Profile and just regular PC.

Comment: Hmm. Perhaps you could post more of the code? Particularly the complete XAML of the DataGrid. Does the hang happen after you assign the data (the `Conversations = list;` part). Are you sure that you are assigning it only once and the data doesn't change afterward?

Comment: I'm assigning only once and hang happens right after Conversations = list;

Comment: You may need to look into data virtualization as well.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar situation yesterday (that's how I found this post) and after much struggle, this is the lesson I learnt. I hope it helps others too.

**The problem is that the width property of the container grid of the datagrid is set to Auto**. My datagrid only has about 500 rows with 5 columns in each row, but in this Auto mode, it is hanging for ever. Once I changed it to * or a fixed width. It's up right away.